# Check user input against words in text file

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell, grep

I am working on an option for my program and it should work like this:

1. user inputs title
2. user inputs author
3. system then checks user's title & author input in the text file named BookDB.txt
4. if there is already existing record in the text file, system will prompt an error
5. else it will continue user to input price, quantity available and quantity sold.
6. book will then be added

I tried playing around with grep but to no avail.
Below are my codes for this particular function.

```
function fnAddBook()
{
echo "Title: "
read inputTitle
echo "Author: "
read inputAuthor

if grep -Fq "$inputTitle" BookDB.txt; then
     if grep -Fq "$inputAuthor" BookDB.txt; then
     echo "Error!"
  fi
else
  echo "Price: "
  read inputPrice
  echo "$inputTitle:$inputAuthor:$inputPrice" >> BookDB.txt
  echo "New Book successfully added!"
fi
}
```

contents of BookDB.txt
format of the contents | Title:Author:Price:QtyAvail:QtySold

```
Hello World:Andre:10.50:10:5
Three Little Pig:Andrew Lim:89.10:290:189
All About Ubuntu:Ubuntu Team:76.00:55:133
Catch Me If You Can:Mary Ann:23.60:6:2
Happy Day:Mary Ann:12.99:197:101
```

**UPDATED PROBLEM:
In this case, even if I typed "Catch Me If You Can" as title + "Ubuntu Team" as Author, it raises the error. How can I modify the codes such that it checks line by line?**

Thanks in advance to those who helped! :)

Comment: Please be more specific about the "no avail" part.

Comment: error messages should go to stderr: echo "Error!" >&2

Comment: the error messages work now. now it boils down to checking of every line in the file for any existing title+author records.

Comment: Agrajag's answer explains the "updated problem" (see second problem) and his solution does not have that problem. It was written before you edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 problems with your code.

The first is that the x option to grep causes it to match only complete lines, and since you put author and title on the same line, this will not match.

With the x option "Gaiman" does not match "Gaiman:Nation:$20", if you remove the x from the grep-options, this will work.

The second problem is that the two greps are independent of eachother. Thus if you have a book titled 'Nation' and a book by 'Gaiman' it will be considered a match, even if the 'Nation' book you have is 'The wealth of Nations' and the Gaiman book you've got is 'Anansi Boys'.

The third problem is that grep will find partial matches. If you try to enter the book "It", then grep will conclude it's already in the database, because "It came from the desert" is.

You need a sentinel-value to delineate the titles to fix this. (the sentinel must be some character that cannot exist in book-titles or author-names)

```
function fnAddBook()
{
echo "Title: "
read inputTitle
echo "Author: "
read inputAuthor
if grep -Fq "$inputTitle:inputAuthor:" BookDB.txt
then
    echo "Error!"
else
   echo "Price: "
   read inputPrice
   echo "$inputTitle:$inputAuthor:$inputPrice" >> BookDB.txt
   echo "New Book successfully added!"
fi
}
```

This assumes that ':' cannot occur in authornames or booknames.

Comment: you are right I have taken the x function out of grep and it searches for any existing word in the file. Do you have any idea how can i solve this?

Comment: Adding `^` before `$inputTitle` in grep expression can help also. And thinking of a good sentinel value, I'd use `$'\t'` aka the tab character. Never met it in a book title or author name (unlike colon).

Comment: @choroba i dont really get you here. any idea how could I check it line by line instead? so that at least I will be able to check against the integrity of the existing Title+Author in every line of my text file.

Comment: @Andres: What do you mean? The code in the answer is looking for line that has that particular title AND author. What else do you need?